# Ubuntu top bar gone transparent, themes not working, No notification icons

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

Problem :

Today I was installing gtk+3.12 and i installed some dependencies!

This has messed up my installation and i have lost the top bar which shows as transparent and also the notifications icons are missing, although the respective packages are present. Also the settings look like windows classic.

[image]

What i have tried
Resetting unity
Reinstalling unity desktop
Reinstalling unity themes

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Kindly help!

Comment: its great some one downvoted it! because from their high standards of knowledge this is downrated question! not thinking of the situation or problems OP faced before asking this question. Why in the world we bar people from asking questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Unity is based on the GTK stack and Ubuntu uses a slightly modified version of it you can't just install another version.

Remove GTK+3.12 and any dependencies that are not from the Ubuntu repositories and install Ubuntu's version of GTK

Comment: Most of the dependencies were from ubuntu repositories, except the gtk+ which i downloaded and was trying to build from source

Comment: As said by you! removed gtk and dependecies! broke my desktop! reinstalled ubuntu desktop and unity! all is well now! thanx for the valueable suggestion!